# Global array in module file

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-charts

I have issue

```
file 1:
 Module1 - file name
```

In this file I need to declare global array, something like

```
Dim array1(100) As Integer
```

And in another file, this is UserForm - I need change values of this array

```
Module1.array1(2) = 1995 //for example
```

How can I do it?

I have a compile error: wrong number of dimensions

Comment: You do that `Dim` outside of any `Sub()` or `Function()`. It will be a "Global" variable that will be available to outside functions and subroutines. `Public array1(100) as Integer`

Comment: As your code is given, I get a different error (Method or Data Member not found). If @JNevill 's comment doesn't resolve the problem (I think it should), please provide more context in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: What @JNevill said - no need for the `Module1` at the start of your variable because if you use `Public array1(100) as Integer`, then you can explicitly reference it no problem from any module. Except I believe JNevill accidentally left `Dim` in there, no need for that :).

Comment: @dwirony good catch. Removed from the comment.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to define a global or public variable, you need to (a) define it outside of a function/sub definition, and (b) use global or public.

So in your module:

```
Public array1(100) As Integer
```

And in your form:

```
array1(0) = 1995
```